# Is this a problem Deploying Heroku before working in AWS?

Tags: django, amazon-s3, heroku

I've deployed my site on Heroku with no problems. After that, I've uploaded my static and media folder to AWS and i get this error:

```
raise ImproperlyConfigured("Could not load Boto3's S3 bindings. %s" % e)
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Could not load Boto3's S3 bindings.
 No module named 'boto3'
```

I've installed everything, I've done `pip freeze < requirements.text`.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

```
 I had to replace following using python3

boto==2.45.0

With

boto3==1.4.4

In requirements/production.txt and push to heroku again.

I also had to replace

MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/%s/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
with

MEDIA_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/%s/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
STATIC_URL = 'https://s3.amazonaws.com:443/%s/static/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
in config/settings/production.py. But not sure it this last thing is just my problem
```